# VB.NET Textfieldparser starts from 2nd line

Tags: vb.net, textfieldparser

I got a text file, for example :

```
firstline
secondline
thirdline
fourthline
fifthline
```

by using `textfieldparser` method, How do i start from the second line and stop at the fourth line? 
and try to parse each line with fieldwidths {2,4,3,1}.

this is the result output i expect to be:

```
se cond lin e
th irdl ine 0
fo urth lin e
```

Comment: `.ReadLine()` to skip the first line, and then 3 `.ReadFields()` to read lines 2, 3 and 4

Comment: thanks! I put `textfieldparser.linenumber > -1` on while `textfieldparser.readline` while loop

Comment: I just realized that I only got the even rows.. the odd rows are missing.. Did i do some mistake?

Comment: You probably have a .Readline() to much in your loop